# Finding names in List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new to programming and to this forum. I have searched the forum for answers but havent found anything that works for me. I have created a adressbook in WinForms with a search function. The search finds the the specified contact, but when I click on the contact the information it loads belongs to the first contact in the List. This happens for every contact in the list exept for the first contact.

```
var TempVar = People.Where(a => a.Namn.ToLower().Contains(txtSearchbar.Text.ToLower()) ||
            a.PostOrt.ToLower().Contains(txtSearchbar.Text.ToLower())).ToList();

            foreach (var item in TempVar)
            {
                ListBoxOne.Items.Add(TempVar);
            }
```

Tell me if you need more information. Thanks for all the help!!

EDIT1:

Dont know if this is the right way to answer, but the comment section didnt let me post a long answer.

For starters. Thanks for being so helpful. I tried your code for adding to the list, but got the errorcode: Cannot convert System.Collecion.Generic.List  to System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection. Searched the web  for a solution but came up short. Shall I post my entire code?  Also tried your search code  it works great. But my main problem is still there. When I click on the search results the name in the listbox shows the contact information of the first contact in the  entire contactlist. Its as if the index of the contacts is still in the listbox but when contacts in the Listbox are sorted out by the search function the first contacts index is given to the contact the search found. Shall I post my entire code to make everything clearer.? Thanks for all the help!

EDIT2: Here is the code. I got a class with person propertys. Name, adress, postnummber, city, telephone annd email that links to the list.

I know some of the comments are in swedish and it is a hassle. Ask me if there is anything you donte understand.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    List<Person> People = new List<Person>();//Skapar en lista med alla variabler i Person

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Reads file on start up.
    {
        //string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (Directory.Exists("C:\\visualFolder\\Adressbok"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\visualFolder\\Adressbok");
        }
        if (!File.Exists("C:\\visualFolder\\Adressbok\\settings.xml"))
        {
            XmlTextWriter XW = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\visualFolder\\Adressbok\\settings.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            XW.WriteStartElement("People");
            XW.WriteEndElement();
            XW.Close();
        }
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("C:\\visualFolder\\Adressbok\\settings.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode XNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("People/Person"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Namn = XNode.SelectSingleNode("Namn").InnerText;
            p.GatuAdress = XNode.SelectSingleNode("Adress").InnerText;
            p.PostNummer = XNode.SelectSingleNode("Postnummer").InnerText;
            p.PostOrt = XNode.SelectSingleNode("Postort").InnerText;
            p.Telefon = XNode.SelectSingleNode("Telefon").InnerText;
            p.Email = XNode.SelectSingleNode("Email").InnerText;
            People.Add(p);
            ListBoxOne.Items.Add(p.Namn);


        }

    }//----

    private void cmdRegistrera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Adds contact
    {
        Person LäggTillPerson = new Person();
        LäggTillPerson.Namn = txtNamn.Text;
        LäggTillPerson.GatuAdress = txtAdressText.Text;
        LäggTillPerson.PostNummer = txtPostNummer.Text;
        LäggTillPerson.PostOrt = txtPostOrt.Text;
        LäggTillPerson.Telefon = txtTelefonnummer.Text;
        LäggTillPerson.Email = txtEpost.Text;
        People.Add(LäggTillPerson);
        ListBoxOne.Items.Add(LäggTillPerson.Namn);

        txtNamn.Clear();
        txtAdressText.Clear();
        txtPostNummer.Clear();
        txtPostOrt.Clear();
        txtTelefonnummer.Clear();
        txtEpost.Clear();

    }

    private void cmdTaBort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Deletes contact.
    {

        if (ListBoxOne.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            People.RemoveAt(ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex);
            ListBoxOne.Items.Remove(ListBoxOne.SelectedItems[0]);
        }


        txtNamn.Clear();
        txtAdressText.Clear();
        txtPostNummer.Clear();
        txtPostOrt.Clear();
        txtTelefonnummer.Clear();
        txtEpost.Clear();

    }


    private void ListboxOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//
    {
        if (ListBoxOne.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            txtNamn.Text = People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].Namn;
            txtAdressText.Text = People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].GatuAdress;
            txtPostNummer.Text = People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].PostNummer;
            txtPostOrt.Text = People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].PostOrt;
            txtTelefonnummer.Text = People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].Telefon;
            txtEpost.Text = People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].Email;
        }

    }

    private void cmdSpara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Saves changes.
    {
        if (ListBoxOne.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].Namn = txtNamn.Text;
            People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].GatuAdress = txtAdressText.Text;
            People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].PostNummer = txtPostNummer.Text;
            People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].PostOrt = txtPostOrt.Text;
            People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].Telefon = txtTelefonnummer.Text;
            People[ListBoxOne.SelectedIndex].Email = txtEpost.Text;

            ListBoxOne.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var item in People)
            {
                ListBoxOne.Items.Add(item.Namn);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Ändringarna är sparade");

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)//Saves to file on when closin the application.
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("C:\\visualFolder\\Adressbok\\settings.xml");
        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("People");
        xNode.RemoveAll();

        foreach (Person p in People)
        {
            XmlNode xTop = xDoc.CreateElement("Person");
            XmlNode Xnamn = xDoc.CreateElement("Namn");
            XmlNode Xadress = xDoc.CreateElement("Adress");
            XmlNode XPostnummer = xDoc.CreateElement("Postnummer");
            XmlNode XpostOrt= xDoc.CreateElement("Postort");
            XmlNode Xtelefon = xDoc.CreateElement("Telefon");
            XmlNode XeMAil = xDoc.CreateElement("Email");

            Xnamn.InnerText = p.Namn;
            Xadress.InnerText = p.GatuAdress;
            XPostnummer.InnerText = p.PostNummer;
            XpostOrt.InnerText = p.PostOrt;
            Xtelefon.InnerText = p.Telefon;
            XeMAil.InnerText = p.Email;

            xTop.AppendChild(Xnamn);
            xTop.AppendChild(Xadress);
            xTop.AppendChild(XPostnummer);
            xTop.AppendChild(XpostOrt);
            xTop.AppendChild(Xtelefon);
            xTop.AppendChild(XeMAil);

            xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop);

        }
        xDoc.Save("C:\\visualFolder\\Adressbok\\settings.xml"); 


    }

    private void cmdSök_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Search function. This is where the problem is. 
    {

        if (txtSearchbar.Text != "")
        {

            var term = txtSearchbar.Text;
            var results = People.Where(a => ContainsCI(a.Namn, term)
                                         || ContainsCI(a.PostOrt, term));

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                ListBoxOne.Items.Add(item);
            }

            ListBoxOne.Items.Clear();


            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                ListBoxOne.Items.Add(item.Namn);
            }
            txtSearchbar.Clear();


        }

        else
        {
            ListBoxOne.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var item in People)
            {
                ListBoxOne.Items.Add(item.Namn);
            }


        }

    }

    private void cmdClearSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Clears the searchebar and ListBox and loads the contacts again.
    {
        ListBoxOne.Items.Clear();
        txtSearchbar.Clear();

        foreach (var item in People)
        {
            ListBoxOne.Items.Add(item.Namn);
        }


        txtNamn.Clear();
        txtAdressText.Clear();
        txtPostNummer.Clear();
        txtPostOrt.Clear();
        txtTelefonnummer.Clear();
        txtEpost.Clear();

    }

    public bool ContainsCI(string input, string term)//Search function. courtesy of Panagiotis Kanavos
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            return false;
        }
        //Returns true even if `terms` is empty, just like String.Contains
        return input.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `ListBoxOne.Items.Add(TempVar);` you definitely want `ListBoxOne.Items.Add(item);`

Comment: I can´t see neither a `Contact`-class nor an `adressBook` nor anything else related to this question.

Comment: Better yet, `AddRange(TempVar)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a typo. Instead of adding individual items you keep adding the list itself to the listbox. You should add the individual items:

```
foreach (var item in TempVar)
{
    ListBoxOne.Items.Add(item);
}
```

A better option though would be to use `AddRange` to add the entire list at once:

```
ListBoxOne.Items.AddRange(TempVar);
```

You can improve the rest of the code as well. Instead of `Contains` which is case sensitive, you can use [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) with a case-insensitive StringComparison parameter. To make the code a bit cleaner, I created a separate `ContainsCI` method:

```
public bool ContainsCI(string input, string term)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(input))
  {
       return false;
  }
  //Returns true even if `terms` is empty, just like String.Contains
  return input.IndexOf(term,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)!= -1);
}

...

var term=txtSearchbar.Text;
var results= People.Where(a => ContainsCI(a.Namn, term)
                            || ContainsCI(a.PostOrt,term));

ListBoxOne.Items.AddRange(results);
```

By using `IndexOf` instead of `Contains` and `ToLower()` the code avoids generating temporary strings which end up wasting memory for no gain.

Note that both `String.Contains` and `ContainsCI` return `true` if the term is empty. This makes it easy to return all items if the search box is empty.

Comment: Answered in my main question above. The comment box didnt let me giv an long answer.